# Convert em units to pixel in SVG

Tags: svg, glyphs

I have converted some svg fonts into `path`s and saved them in a svg file. I then `use` the `path`s (by referencing the paths using the `xlink:href` attribute of the `use` element) to use the converted font glyphs in another svg drawing but i want some reasonable horizontal space between glyphs. I know i am doing it wrong, but what i did was to multiply the `horiz-adv-x` of the original `font` element (`horiz-adv-x="246"`) by 16 (since 1em = 16 pixels) as the default horizontal value to be added to the x coordinates of the drawn glyphs. This generates a huge horizontal distance. My question is first are the `horiz-adv-x` values in em units and how should i get a reasonable horizontal space for my converted glyphs considering these values (by reasonable i mean so that the font glyphs are not overlapped by each other)?

Comment: 1em is only 16px if it's defined in the document root, it's a relative unit.

Comment: `horiz-adv-s` has been deprecated and, according to ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/horiz-adv-x ) has virtually no browser support. Perhaps this explains unexepected behavior?